# How can I update the contents of an entry in the Call Log?

Tags: android, calllog

I would like to update the `CallLog.Calls.TYPE` field of the first entry in the Android Call Log from `MISSED` to `INCOMING`.  I have read books, the developers reference and googled this to death and am reasonably sure that my code is correct. However, when I actually make the call to `update()`, the result is that no record is updated.  My code sample is below.

Before you ask:
  - I have permissions for `WRITE_CONTACTS`
  - The record to be updated (0) does exist
  - I have tried this on both a DroidX (Verizon) and a Samsung Galaxy (AT&T)
  - I have tried various other, longer forms of this code with same result

Can someone please help with this?

```
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE);
    newValues.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 50);
    int result = OsmoService.context.getContentResolver().update(
    ContentUris.withAppendedId(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 0), 
    newValues,null,null);
```

Comment: When you make this change. Just after call was missed or some reasonable time later?

Answer (score 1):

If you update your code above and replace the line:

```
ContentUris.withAppendedId(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 0)
```

with this line:

```
Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls")
```

It works.  I don't know why, but something is not correct with the content URI.

example:

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE);
newValues.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 50);
int result = OsmoService.context.getContentResolver().update(
    Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"), 
    newValues,
    null,
    null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  After pouring over traces, I actually found where my error was.  I had been assuming that in the following, xxx was a row number:  "content://call_log/calls/xxx".  However, from the URIs returned from inserting a new entry, I found that xxx actually needed to be the _ID field of the record.  All works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,"7070770"); // contact number

cv.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE,1); // type

cv.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 120); // duration in second


getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

Comment: can you also explain a bit ??

Answer (score 0):

for example CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME

```
private void updateCachedName(int id, @NonNull String name) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, name);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        getContext().getContentResolver().update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, contentValues, CallLog.Calls._ID + "=" + id, null);
    }
}
```