# Android - writing manually to call log

Tags: android

I have app that intercepts outgoing call. With some filtering, I'm hanging up the call. The problem is, that I want to see that call in outgoing call log. Since I'm hanging up the call in code, it doesn't write the entry of it. How can I manually add to call log please?

Answer (score 0):

You need `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` (and maybe `READ_CONTACTS` as well), then you can access the call log.

Here is code to [read the call log](http://malsandroid.blogspot.com/2010/06/accessing-call-logs.html) and to [update an entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794722/539443). You should be able to `insert()` into the content provider the same way.