# Writing call log in an Android device

Tags: android, calllog

I have created a fake caller, and one place I'm stuck is writing the call logs.

Can someone explain how to write a call log and what permissions are required for this?

I found an answer at [How can I update the contents of an entry in the Call Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635874/how-can-i-update-the-contents-of-an-entry-in-the-call-log/5794722#5794722) but in that answer the term `OsmoService` is not defined. I'm not able to understand if that is a predefined class or user defined class.

Your help will be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910906/i-want-read-call-logs-in-the-android

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May this help you:

Add this permission in your *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
```

**Code:**

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, number);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 0);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "");
values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");
context.getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: You spent time on it, Thank you very much. But your answer seems to adding a new contact. What I actually want is inserting a call log (Incoming call log). Thanks buddy

Answer (score -1):

Check this link for call log accessing

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android/6786962#6786962)

Permission for this access is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```